# Can I use google API to convert a PDF into PNGs?

Tags: pdf, png, gdata-api, google-api, google-data-api

I have noticed that when you view PDFs in google docs the PDF viewer renders the PDF file into PNG images.

**I was wondering if you could use Google Data API to upload a PDF and get the URLs of the rendered PNG files?**

*I have never used the google API or really had the extra time to learn it, but if it help me do this it will be well worth the extra time.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't do it.
Google [explicitly](http://code.google.com/intl/it/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#DownloadingOtherFiles) does not allow it.

> Downloading PDFs and arbitrary files
>
> Native PDF files cannot be exported in
>   a format other than .pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it.. I think it would be easier/more stable to use imagemagick or some other library to handle this. Converting PDFs to images usign imagemagick is just one CLI command.

Comment: I wrote script that does this with ghostscript but I have limited access to the servers that the website I need it for will be on. So I was planning on write a web service that will convert a PDF to PNG files and send an array of URL paths. I was just wondering if there was already a service out there already that could do this.

Comment: btw I love answers that start out "I doubt it" or "probably not". That's like saying "I don't know. I just wanted to be the first person to post on this thread"

Comment: Is this still true in 2021? Can you access ImageMagick or ghostscript from Google App Scripts.